# Запись и чтение в файл через pickle

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу разобраться с записью/чтением в файл.
Есть код:

```
import pickle
result = {'vova':'8', 'stepa': '6', 'primer':'9', 'vovas': '12'}
dee = open('dadt.dat','ab')
pickle.dump(result,dee)
dee.close()
dee = open('dadt.dat','rb')
der = pickle.load(dee)
for i in der:
    print(i, der[i])
```

Что я ожидаю от него - выводить то что есть в файле, если меняю список `result` - дописывать новые значения (проверка на дубли за рамками задачи).

Что получаю - вывод корректно производится один раз, однако при изменении словаря и повторной записи - выводит то же самое, что и в первый раз.

Скажем меняю result на

```
result = {'vova':'8', 'stepa': '6', 'primer':'9', 'vovas': '12', 'novoe':'12'}
```

А получаю такой же вывод, как и в первом случае.

Подскажите, что делаю не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что вы считываете значение из файла только один раз. pickle не даёт возможности синхронизации файла с переменной, поэтому вам нужно осуществлять это самостоятельно каждый раз.

Также если вы открываете файл на добавление (ключ `'a'`), то содержимое переменной запишется в конец файла (т.е. при втором вызове в файле будет записано уже две переменных, при третьем -- три и так далее). Функция `pickle.load` считывает за один вызов только один объект из файла, поэтому вам придётся вызывать её несколько раз, чтобы добраться до последней сохранённой переменной.

Если я правильно понял вашу задачу, вам не нужно хранить разные состояния вашей переменной, а достаточно только последнего, но обновлённого. Для этого нужно открывать файл на чтение (ключ `'w'`), что будет перезаписывать файл каждый раз, когда вы сохраняете обновления вашей переменной.

После этого просто сохраняйте переменную тогда, когда вам нужно учесть её обновления и загружайте их из файла дампа при необходимости синхронизации с записанным в файл состоянием.

```
import pickle
result = {'vova':'8', 'stepa': '6', 'primer':'9', 'vovas': '12'}

# сохраняем словарь в файл
with open('dump.dat', 'wb') as dump_out:
    pickle.dump(result, dump_out)

# загружаем словарь из файла
with open('dump.dat', 'rb') as dump_in:
    der = pickle.load(dump_in)

for key, value in der.items():
    print(key, value)

# обновляем словарь
result = {'vova':'8', 'stepa': '6', 'primer':'9', 'vovas': '12', 'novoe':'12'}

# снова сохраняем словарь в файл
with open('dump.dat', 'wb') as dump_out:
    pickle.dump(result, dump_out)

# снова загружаем словарь из файла
with open('dump.dat', 'rb') as dump_in:
    der = pickle.load(dump_in)

for key, value in der.items():
    print(key, value)
```

Также обратите внимание на конструкцию `with` для работы с файлами и на метод `.items()` у словаря, который возвращает генератор всех пар ключ-значение этого словаря.